# Can't compute homography

Tags: matlab, camera-calibration, homography

I'm quite inexperienced with Matlab and image processing, and I've been struggling with this problem for the past few days.

I have a 12 point correspondence between coplanar plane coordinates and their image projections. I also know the intrinsics of the camera. From what I understood, this is enough to compute the homography. (My final goal is to obtain the extrinsic parameters of the camera, which I believe is straightforward after computing the homography H.)

I've tried different methods to obtain H, but I get a different matrix with each method/function I try, when apparently they all have the same input/output. For example, using vgg_H_from_x_lin(X1,X2) found here http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/code/ and homography_solve from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26141-homography-matrix gives me 2 completely different matrices.

I've tried this as well, https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse252a/homography_estimation/homography_estimation.pdf , which led me to another different H.

What am I doing wrong here? This should be quite simple as I have the point correspondence and the camera intrinsics, but I can't understand how to compute H correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've done this, but have you tried any of the homography matrices to see if your plane co-ordinates match with the image projections?  You realize that homography matrices are all equivalent up to a scale factor, so though you may be getting different answers, try reprojecting the co-ordinates and seeing if they actually match with the image co-ordinates you have.  To remove this scale factor business, you can normalize the homography matrix.  Check that MathWorks post that you linked to and read the bottom comment.  If you normalize, I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realize that H matrices are equivalent up to a scale factor, but I compared them and they didn't fit any scaling factor. I've tested the resulting H (at least I think I did, check if HX=x right?) and it doesn't seem to be right. This is probably a stupid mistake I'm making, but it's driving me crazy. BTW, using that MathWorks function, do I need to process my coordinates in any way before applying it?

Comment: What "doesn't seem to be right"?  Yes, you're applying the homography correctly.  There shouldn't be a need to process your co-ordinates.  The homography matrix takes care of the scaling for you.  Did you try normalizing the homography matrix like what the MathWorks comment at the bottom of that post said?

Comment: I seem to have discovered the problem, which was not related to the computing of the homography. I believe I wasn't converting the xyz coordinates correctly, and so the H was incorrect. Thanks

Comment: Haha no worries.  I didn't solve anything though!